# Add a dynamic grid as input in custom extension Admin HTML from phtml file.

Tags: php, magento, grid, renderer

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE1.7.0.2

you can see here i want to get like this in my custom module

[image]

Here is my `Form.php`

```
<?php
class Company_Web_Block_Adminhtml_Web_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
      $this->setForm($form);
      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('web_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('web')->__('Item information')));

      $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Title'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'title',
      ));

      $fieldset->addField('filename', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('File'),
          'required'  => false,
          'name'      => 'filename',
      ));

      $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Status'),
          'name'      => 'status',
          'values'    => array(
              array(
                  'value'     => 1,
                  'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Enabled'),
              ),

              array(
                  'value'     => 2,
                  'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Disabled'),
              ),
          ),
      ));

      $fieldset->addField('content', 'editor', array(
          'name'      => 'content',
          'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Content'),
          'title'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Content'),
          'style'     => 'width:700px; height:500px;',
          'wysiwyg'   => false,
          'required'  => true,
      ));

      if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getWebData() )
      {
          $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getWebData());
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setWebData(null);
      } elseif ( Mage::registry('web_data') ) {
          $form->setValues(Mage::registry('web_data')->getData());
      }
      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
}
```

How do i get this ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: You need to use renderer to add / delete your custom options

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy thanks for the fast reply... If its possible means can i have some useful articles for that.

Comment: you can see here is very good tutorial with detail understand
http://mustakarhu.com/blog/dynamic-input-field-in-magento-admin-configuration/ AND see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/best-way-to-add-a-dynamic-grid-as-input-in-custom-extension-adminhtml
hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Create a Renderer file like below

> **NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\ModuleName\Edit\Renderer\Display.php**

The file relates to below code `adminhtml_modulename_edit_renderer_display`

Try adding below fieldset in your Form.php

```
<?php
        // This code is being used to sort the renderer display in form using element of your own
        $fieldset->addType('modulename', Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('modulename/adminhtml_modulename_edit_renderer_display'));
        $fieldset->addField('yourdbfield_name', 'modulename', array(
        'name' => 'yourdbfield_name',
        'label' => Mage::helper('modulename')->__('Title you want to show'),
        'required' => true,
        ));
        // This code is being used to sort the renderer display in form using element of your own
?>
```

You can also add renderer like this

```
'renderer' => 'modulename/adminhtml_modulename_edit_renderer_display',
```

Now in your display.php add below **HTML** code along with the JS code.

```
<table id="modulename_tbl_data" cellspacing="0">
    <button id="add_your_component" class="add" type="button" title="Add"><span><span><span>Add</span></span></span></button>
</table>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
jQee('#add_your_component').click(function() {
        var jQee = jQuery.noConflict();
        jQee(document).ready(function(){
        var i = jQee('input').size() + 1;

        jQee('#add').click(function() { 

        var one = '<input id="yourID" name="yourName[]" value="" class="required-entry validate-number input-text required-entry"/>';

        var remove = '<button onclick="javascript:jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove();" class="delete" type="button" title="Remove"><span><span><span>Remove</span></span></span></button>';

        var tr = '<tr class="div_class"><td style="padding:0px 10px;">'+one+'</td><td style="padding:0px 10px;">'+remove+'</td></tr>';  
        jQuery('#modulename_tbl_data').append(tr);

        i++;
    });

    });
```

This will allow you add options and remove them just like Magento.

Note: This is a just a demo and not complete code. You can alter it according to your needs.

Comment: but this will save data attribute to serialize?